# Bootstrap::FrameworkNotFound on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I am using rails 3.2 and have built an application on my development server and it is working fine. But when I deploy the same application to my heroku account I get this error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.3.0.1/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb:18:in `load!': bootstrap-sass requires either Rails > 3.1 or Compass, neither of which are loaded (Bootstrap::FrameworkNotFound)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it. The bootstrap-sass gem is a dependency for the rails_admin gem.

Comment: Just took out sass-rails gem from the assets group in my gemfile and the precompiled my assets and then redeployed on heroku and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gemfile

```
 gem 'less-rails'
```

Try this,it might work for you.I got somewhat similar error and i resolved using this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply nikhil but what I did was took out sass-rails gem from asset group in gemfile and then precompiled my assets and that worked for me.